# Why does my Asp.Net Core app, running as MS-service, immediately stop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, config, .net-core-3.1

I wrote an Asp.Net Core app which is supposed to run as a MS-service in the back, however whenever I start it, it immediately stops. The URLs for my service are being read from a .config file and everything seems to work when normally starting my app.

I first published my app using Jetbrain's Rider with the following settings:
[image: publish - settings]

Then I tried to add it with the following command:

```sh
sc.exe create MyService binPath= "some\path\to\publish\to\MyService.exe"
```

It worked, and starting it via `sc.exe start MyService` also returned me a success message, however whenever I look at the list of services running in the Windows 10 tool, it says that my service stopped. Does the reading of URLs have something to do with it? If so, how else should I read my URLs from external sources?

Program.cs, CreateHostBuilder():

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
                .ConfigureWebHost(config =>
                    {
                        //Set the urls and ports where the service should run.
                        config.UseUrls(Config.HttpsUrl, Config.HttpUrl);
                        //Run as MS service.
                    })
                .UseWindowsService();
```

When adding it as a MS-service I looked at the following [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/host-an-asp-net-core-application-as-a-windows-service/).

Comment: Is your `.config` file in the path of the service?

Comment: As in, is it set to copy to the directory for you to then use in the actual service?

Comment: When I published it, it created a file called `MyService.dll.config` in which my values are stored, and changing it also changed the port, for example (when simply running it by double-clicking the generated .exe file).

Comment: What are the filenames for everything published?

Comment: Are there some errors logged in the eventlog?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary MyService.exe, App.config, MyService.dll.config, and a bunch of other .dll and .pdb files

Comment: @Steeeve Where can I see the error log? I didn't specifically add something to my program like that.

Comment: I meant the standard windows application event log. You don't have to do anything special to log errors thrown by windows services there.

Comment: @TH Every service in Windows can write to the event log - open up `eventvwr.exe`

Comment: @Steeeve Got it:
Unable to start Kestrel.
Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

Comment: Running `dotnet dev-certs https --trust'` returns `Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.` and restarting the service still causes it to stop.

Comment: Well, then the reason should be clear. You'll have to provide a certificate if you want to use https. If the service is using the system account, the certificate should be installed in the computer certificate store. Your dev-certs are in your personal store.

Comment: @Steeeve Running the above command didn't help me, so I entered `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` followed by `dotnet dev-certs https --trust'`. After that I restarted my service, but the same error keeps happening.

Comment: @TH Place it in `Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates` - it should be somewhere in `Personal/Certificates` with the name of `HTTPS development certificate` issued to `localhost` issued by `localhost`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I performed the commands while in the directory where I published my project to.

Comment: Like Steve said, your service is probably running under the system account - copy to the location I've mentioned above, restart and it should work

Comment: The dev certs are not supported, as stated by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-endpoints). Please read also [Kestrel endpoint configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You could try to export the dev certs by using certmgr.msc and import them with certlm.msc, but that is not suitable for a production environment.

Comment: @Steeeve @ErmiyaEskandary I imported the certificate to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates` and restarted my service, but it still gives me the same error in the event log.